# How to configure C# solutions to fail on any code style violations?

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, resharper, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I created a sample Web API project and want to enforce coding conventions during my CI pipeline ( bonus points if the style errors come up during development ). Basically I just want to setup eslint ( from the JavaScript world ) for C# projects.

I want to enforce those rules solution wide so I added a [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) file in the root directory with the following content ( I want to use the [Roslyn Analyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers#microsoftcodeanalysisnetanalyzers) and fail on warnings )

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Compiler Settings">
     <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
     <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
     <AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>
     <AnalysisLevel>latest</AnalysisLevel>
     <WarningLevel>5</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Next I installed [dotnet format](https://github.com/dotnet/format#how-to-use) to get access to the `dotnet format ./MySln.sln --verify-no-changes` command.

I modified the generated *WeatherForecastController* to

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;

namespace LinterCheckSample.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        string unused = "";

        return
            new
                List
                <
                    WeatherForecast
                >
                ()
                {
new                                                 WeatherForecast() {}
                };
    }
    
    private void Do() { }
}
```

When running the format command I expected the following things, some got identified

- Redundant import of `System` ❌
- `Summaries` is never used ✅
- Redundant array creation expression for `Summaries` ❌
- `_logger` is never used ❌
- `unused` is never used ✅
- Redundant type specification for `WeatherForecast` ❌
- Whitespace errors ✅
- Remove empty lines in `Get` method ❌
- Fix indentation in `Get` method ❌
- Method `Do` is never used ❌

I think the one thing I'm missing is an .editorconfig file? I copy pasted the [Roslyn Analyzers .editorconfig](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/.editorconfig) into my project and this helped a little bit ( it didn't catch all of them )

If my approach is the correct way is there something I can improve? ( `Directory.Build.props` file ) and is there one official super strict .editorconfig?

If my approach is wrong, what is the correct way to solve this in the C# world?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By using -v diag parameter I can see that the tool is referring to couple .editorconfig files (the one I put in sln root, the one come from the SDK's and the one produced by msbuild). And it looks that different .editorconfig files are giving different formatting corrections. You might want to check with contributors of dotnet-format to see if they have an all-in-one .editorconfig that you can use as baseline.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that's not possible with R# Command Line Tools.

For Roslyn analyzers, it could help setting `TreatWarningsAsErrors` within your `csproj` file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change your `.csproj` files. In the solution directory, add a [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) file with the following:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Compiler Settings">
     <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
     <AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>
     <WarningLevel>5</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Adjust the settings to your needs.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But how would the whole workflow look like? Adding this to the solution, calling dotnet format and add a custom .editorconfig? That's all?